# how to integrate openid with springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openid-provider, openid4java

I'm new to spring boot and I want to integrate openId provider into our application. I have searched a lot about it but didn't find any suitable article from which I can start.

Problem statement:

1. Once user hits our websites url(ex. www.abc.com) the user should be redirected to openID provider's(login page) server where the user puts username and password or register him/herself.
2. After successful authentication, user then given the access to our application where in application needs to retrieve few informations about user (basically data exchange between openID provider and application).
3. how exchange key to generate a shared secret-key?

I have end point of openId provider and service discovery endpoint.

Would someone help me out with this?

Comment: Did you [check this?](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-boot-openid)

Comment: Thanks @CodeItLikeAmeen.